# Why this code will cause my program to be stop working?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
for(user = 0; user <= max; user++)
{
    name[user] = name1;
    password[user] = password1;
}
```

After the program run to this loop it just stopped working and i need to terminate the program. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: This loop is perfectly ok as far as size of `name` and `password` arrays is more than `max`. Probably the error is somewhere else.

Comment: but when I comment out this loop the program is working....

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your question is a bit like "Why does the word 'cupcake' cause my essay to make no sense? It reads just fine without that word." We can hardly say without seeing *where* the work "cupcake" is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying changing your code to:

```
for(user=0; user<max; user++)  // Remove the '=' sign
{
     name[user]=name1;
     password[user]=password1;
}
```

Comment: wow it's works thanks

Comment: can i know why it's work?

Comment: You were exceeding the boundaries of the 'name' and 'password' arrays by 1 element.  A common mistake.

Comment: Hey Weng - can you mark it as the answer? It will be my first one. That was low hanging fruit!

Comment: @WengHou -- Please do not get into the habit of asking questions with little information as you did, and expect persons to be lucky with guessing what is wrong with the program.  Next time, post the entire context of what you're trying to accomplish.  We have no idea what `name` actually is, whether `=` is causing the issue due to improper copy semantics, or yes, whether you are going out of bounds of an array.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time to ask question in this website.I'll try to do what you said next time.